# How to match multiple arrays inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, pdo

m'y question is: How to match multiple arrays (two, or even more) inside a foreach loop (or while)

[image: here is m'y <code>Var_dump</code>]

```
$cat = $bdd->query('SELECT cat_name FROM categories');
$categories_list = $cat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);


$cat_id = $bdd->query('SELECT cat_id FROM categories');
$categories_id = $cat_id->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);


$arrcatid = array($categories_list,$categories_id);

echo '<form method="post" action="accès/create_topic_post.php" autocomplete="off">';
echo '<label for="sujet">Sujet :';
echo '<input type="text" name="sujet" id="sujet" required autofocus>';
echo '</label>';
echo '<label for="cat">Catégories :';
echo '<select name="topic_name">';



foreach ($categories_list as $cat_name){
echo "<option value=\"$cat_name\">$catname</option>";
}
$cat_id->closeCursor();
$cat->closeCursor();


echo '</select>';
echo '</label>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Envoyer">';
echo '</form>';
var_dump($arrcatid);
```

So, the goal is to match array 0 with array 1 `cat_name && cat_id`

Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used :

```
$cat = $bdd->query('SELECT cat_name,cat_id FROM categories');
$categories_list = $cat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

and for the foreach :

```
foreach ($categories_list as $cat_id => $cat_name){
echo "<option value=\"$cat_name\">$cat_id</option>";
```

Comment: This one is good, but I think you need to swap $cat_name and $cat_id, showing names in select field. while id have to be sent to server

Comment: Done :) Thanks for the expertise :D

Answer (score 3):

How about getting both the name and the id in the sql query?

```html
$cat = $bdd->query('SELECT cat_name, cat_id FROM categories');
```

Comment: Then change it to PDO::fetchAll.

Comment: It is already fetchall, `$cat_id ->FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)`

Comment: @RomainSickenberg why don't you read on the parameter you are using? PDO::FETCH_COLUMN is for getting the very first field. If you need other fields, then you need another fetch mode. If you wont read anything on the codes you re given on stack overflow, then no answer will do any good for you. You are here to learn, not to ask other people to do your job.

Comment: Sorry sorry, I thought it talks about the `->FetchAll`